# Run JSP file scripts on back-end server through Android App?

Tags: java, android, jsp, backend

Hi I wanted to know if it is possible to run JSP scripts that are kept on a backend server through an Android App. Basically the user would log in which would give him access to this JSP script he could enter some values like Server X and Option Y press a button that says "Update" in the android app which would pass the selected values to the server and then run the JSP script on the server side to perfrom an update on some backend servers.  I havent seen many resources on this kind of stuff in Android does anyone have any examples? Thanks!

Comment: The fact that it's a JSP is irrelevant for Android: it sends an HTTP  request to a URL, and the request could be handled by anything (a Servlet, a PHP script, an ASP page, whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but if you're asking whether you can send a request over HTTP to a JSP, then yes you can. There are plenty of tips out there; try this one:

[Android Snippets: Executing a HTTP POST Request with HttpClient](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)

Comment: Yes I believe this may be what I am looking for...so my post would look like this line HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.jsp");

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google App Engine for that.
It even comes with a decent free quota.
http://code.google.com/appengine/